# how to limit skype bandwidth?

Tags: skype, bandwidth

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I need to limit skype bandwidth so I could solve problem with video calls.

I have same problem with skype as guy from this link

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Can-I-reduce-the-video-quality-from-high-to-standard/td-p/1156598

and he managed to solve problem with netlimiter but i cant find nothing similar for ubuntu.